# How do I determine if a group of data exists in a table, given the data that should appear in the group's rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, set-operations

I am writing data to a table and allocating a "group-id" for each batch of data that is written.  To illustrate, consider the following table.

```
GroupId  Value
-------  -----
      1      a
      1      b
      1      c
      2      a
      2      b
      3      a
      3      b
      3      c
      3      d
```

In this example, there are three groups of data, each with similar but varying values.

How do I query this table to find a group that contains a given set of values?  For instance, if I query for (a,b,c) the result should be group 1.  Similarly, a query for (b,a) should result in group 2, and a query for (a, b, c, e) should result in the empty set.

I can write a stored procedure that performs the following steps:

- select distinct GroupId from Groups -- and store locally
- for each distinct GroupId: perform a set-difference (`except`) between the input and table values (for the group), and vice versa
- return the GroupId if both set-difference operations produced empty sets

This seems a bit excessive, and I hoping to leverage some other commands in SQL to simplify.  Is there a simpler way to perform a set-comparison in this context, or to select the group ID that contains the exact input values for the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a set-within-sets query.  I like to solve it using `group by` and `having`:

```
select groupid
from GroupValues gv
group by groupid
having sum(case when value = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value not in ('a', 'b', 'c') then 1 else - end) = 0;
```

The first three conditions in the `having` clause check that each elements exists.  The last condition checks that there are no other values.  This method is quite flexible, for various exclusions and inclusion conditions on the values you are looking for.

EDIT:

If you want to pass in a list, you can use:

```
with thelist as (
      select 'a' as value union all
      select 'b' union all
      select 'c'
     )
select groupid
from GroupValues gv left outer join
     thelist
     on gv.value = thelist.value
group by groupid
having count(distinct gv.value) = (select count(*) from thelist) and
       count(distinct (case when gv.value = thelist.value then gv.value end)) = count(distinct gv.value);
```

Here the `having` clause counts the number of matching values and makes sure that this is the same size as the list.

EDIT:
query compile failed because missing the table alias. updated with right table alias.

Comment: how does the user user pass interested value set ? because the interested set values are dynamic and not fixed.

Comment: +1: I'm almost positive the performance of this will be better than my spaghetti logic. :)

Comment: This is very clever!  I believe I can make a further simplification if my values are foreign keys and are guaranteed to be unique within groups.  If this is the case, I should just be able to check that the a group size matches my input set size.  Is this sound?

Comment: @SteveGuidi . . . I don't think you can simplify the `having` clause like that.  You need an exact match between the two groups.  So, you need to be sure they are the same size *and* that there are no missing values.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of ugly, but it works. On larger datasets I'm not sure what performance would look like, but the nested instances of `#GroupValues` key off `GroupID` in the main table so I think as long as you have a good index on `GroupID` it probably wouldn't be too horrible.

```
If      Object_ID('tempdb..#GroupValues') Is Not Null Drop Table #GroupValues
Create  Table #GroupValues (GroupID Int, Val Varchar(10));
Insert  #GroupValues (GroupID, Val)
Values  (1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'c'),(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'a'),(3,'b'),(3,'c'),(3,'d');

If      Object_ID('tempdb..#FindValues') Is Not Null Drop Table #FindValues
Create  Table #FindValues (Val Varchar(10));
Insert  #FindValues (Val)
Values  ('a'),('b'),('c');

Select  Distinct gv.GroupID
From   (Select  Distinct GroupID 
        From    #GroupValues) gv
Where   Not Exists (Select  1
                    From    #FindValues fv2
                    Where   Not Exists (Select  1
                                        From    #GroupValues gv2
                                        Where   gv.GroupID = gv2.GroupID
                                        And     fv2.Val = gv2.Val))
And     Not Exists (Select  1
                    From    #GroupValues gv3
                    Where   gv3.GroupID = gv.GroupID
                    And     Not Exists (Select  1
                                        From    #FindValues fv3
                                        Where   gv3.Val = fv3.Val))
```

Comment: That said, this is more or less a single query version of what you described as putting in your sproc.